# How to configure flycheck (c/c++-clang) to ignore some files or directories?

Tags: flycheck, c++, clang

My C++ code use third-party library, so I have to add the library path to `flycheck-clang-include-path` to avoid can't find header file error.

But I don't want `flycheck` to do the syntax check on that library.

Because it always report warning/error on any file which include header files from that library.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: Do you want to use Flycheck in a C++ file that includes a header from your library while ignoring all errors and warnings from that header, or do you want to visit a file from the library without Flycheck being enabled automatically?

Comment: I am expecting the former one.  But if the solution can do both will be great.

Comment: That's impossible.  You cannot check a file whose includes don't pass the compiler.  Includes are just textual substitutions after all; a single faulty include renders the entire file invalid.  You have to configure Flycheck so that it accepts the includes without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-isystem` compiler option to suppress such warnings.
If you're using a `.dir-locals.el` setup:

```
((c++-mode . ((flycheck-clang-args . ("-isystem/path/to/3rd-party-libs/include")))))
```

In this case you may need to configure that variable content as safe, e.g. in .emacs (if you trust any clang args):

```
(put 'flycheck-clang-args 'safe-local-variable (lambda (xx) t))
```